# Hibernate @Any Annotation and Multiple Join Columns (ie: Composite Key)

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy, orm, hibernate-mapping

Is it possible to use the Hibernate @Any annotation when the object being mapped to has a composite key?  I have tried the following annotation combination:

```
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = 'META_COLUMN'))
@AnyMetaDef(idType = 'string', metaType = 'string', metaValues = [
    @MetaValue(value = 'V1', targetEntity = Object1),
    @MetaValue(value = 'V2', targetEntity = Object1),
    @MetaValue(value = 'V3', targetEntity = Object2)
])
@JoinColumns([
    @JoinColumn(name = 'COLUMN1'),
    @JoinColumn(name = 'COLUMN2'),
    @JoinColumn(name = 'COLUMN3')
])
```

Unfortunately this results in a

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: ca.package.class type: object
```